Gap between F22 ailerons and flaperons
You can see in the below picture that there's an F22 on approach (I think) and this is almost a perfect bottom view of the plane while it's going straight, it isn't banking.
There's gaps between the ailerons and the outward part of the wing, and gaps between the aileron and the flaperons. I thought sealed ailerons were more effective and and a lower drag as show in this answer about external aileron seals.
Is this much of a visible gap negligible?


Due to the high loads sustainable by this kind of airplanes, the structure tends to deform quite a lot (gif source - that's an A350 but it gives anyway an idea of what I mean):

Having moveable surfaces perfectly "sealed" might simply jam them under load, that's why the gaps that you see in that picture.

Deform horizontally?

Besides the fully valid point of @sophit, it must be noted that the flaps, elevators and ailerons of the F-22, F-35 and B-2 have a pillow edge, which means their sides end in a sharp edge to reduce side emissions of electromagnetic radiation. This makes the gap visible at odd angles where conventional control surfaces with a triangular side would block the light. The gaps themselves are not larger than those of comparable airplanes.

@AadirajAnil Imagine the wings bending up, causing the top edges of the gap to come closer together.

This answer sounds sound, I'll wait for anything else and mark it. I think the information about pillow edges added by @PeterKämpf is also supporting this answer well.
